# Using nameof() with Url.Action() and async methods in ASP.NET Core 3.x MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-core-3.0, nameof

Let's say I have a ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC application, which features a simple controller containing two actions and using attribute based routing:

```cs
[Route("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static string ControllerName { get; } = "Home";

    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    string GenerateUrls()
    {
        string url1 = Url.Action(nameof(Action1), ControllerName);
        string url2 = Url.Action(nameof(Action2Async), ControllerName);
        return $"Action1: '{url1}'\nAction2: '{url2}'";
    }

    [HttpGet("a1")]
    public IActionResult Action1()
    {
        return Ok(GenerateUrls());
    }

    [HttpGet("a2")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Action2Async()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;

        return Ok(GenerateUrls());
    }
}
```

So calling either action should just yield a page showing URLs for both actions.

Opening `/home/a1` and `/home/a2` correctly calls the respective actions, but the output is kind of unexpected:

```
Action1: '/home/a1'
Action2: ''
```

This indicates that `Url.Action()` returned an empty string for the second action, while it worked perfectly fine for the first action.

After debugging this for quite a while, I found a [blog post](https://www.activesolution.se/bloggat/async-routes-stopped-working-in-asp.net-core-3/) tracking down this very problem to a breaking change in ASP.NET Core 3.0, where the `Async` suffix is somehow ignored by `Url.Action()`.

The author fixed this problem by hard-coding strings as action names (`"Action1"` und `"Action2"` in my case). He also uploaded some [example code](https://github.com/PeterOrneholm/aspnetcore-url-repro) reproducing this behavior.

However, I would really prefer to keep the `nameof`, to avoid later problems with renaming/refactoring.

Is there a clean way to use `nameof` or other type-safe constructs to supply a method with `Async` suffix to the `Url.Action` function?

Comment: You could look at [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) (or R4MVC for Core) for generating strongly-typed helper (parameter) code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but please avoid constellations like `await Task.CompletedTask;` in your code. Use `return Task.FromResult()` instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for that pointer, that looks quite promising! This might also solve the problem with the controller name property...

Comment: @MarcusWichelmann Well, this is more a consequence of simplifying the example as much as possible, but still thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The described behavior is caused by a breaking change introduced with ASP.NET Core 3.0.

You can go back to the old behaviour by disabling [`SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressasyncsuffixinactionnames?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> Gets or sets a value that determines if MVC will remove the suffix "Async" applied to controller action names.

Disable this switch in your `AddControllers` call while configuring the application services:

```
services.AddControllers(options => {
    options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
});
```

You can find more information about this change in the [official announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/351) and in the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14716).

Comment: No, that just makes an un-attributed async-suffixed action method unreachable through the not-suffixed route. While this seems relevant, it's got nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: @CodeCaster As far as I understand the issue, this is exactly what he wants. And as seen in his question, all of his action methods are attributed with the desired route name, so the Async suffix shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Then the problem is that you don't understand it. They want strongly-typed strings out of their action methods, yes? But if you use `nameof(Action2Async)`, you get `"Action2Async"` in your URLs. That doesn't match any route, because their action method is routed (through the attribute `[HttpGet("action2")]`, but would also be by naming convention), through "action2". Requesting "action2Async" is not going to end up in that action method. While your change is going to **require** that, when they would omit the `[HttpGet("action2")]` attribute, they would use the URL "action2Async"!

Comment: So your suggestion comes down to: disable the "remove the async suffix from the route" convention, remove the routing attribute, and just accept that your route is going to be `Action2Async`, which is counterproductive - and results in ugly URLs.

Comment: @CodeCaster I never expected him to remove the routing attribute. This would result in ugly URLs, I agree. I think it is a great convention to always explicitly set the routes by using attributes instead of relying on acion names.

Comment: Thanks! This leads to generation of the desired URLs. It still feels somewhat "messy", making the framework fall back to old behavior. I will take a brief look at other options, but this is definitely a working solution.

Comment: Sorry, but then I don't understand how this works. I'll try and repro...

Answer (score -1):

If you change your method name Action2Async to Action2 the problem will be solved.

From the linked [blog post](https://www.activesolution.se/bloggat/async-routes-stopped-working-in-asp.net-core-3/):

> In ASP.NET Core 3, if you have Action methods suffixed with Async but a route path that does not include Async, refer to them without the Async suffix when resolving a URL through like Url.Action(). This seems to be a breaking change from ASP.NET Core 2.2 which is not officially documented.

```
public static string ControllerName { get; } = "Home";

string GenerateUrls()
{
    string url1 = Url.Action(nameof(Action1), ControllerName);
    string url2 = Url.Action(nameof(Action2), ControllerName);
    return $"Action1: '{url1}'\nAction2: '{url2}'";
}

[HttpGet("action1")]
public IActionResult Action1()
{
    return Ok(GenerateUrls());
}

[HttpGet("action2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Action2()
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;

    return Ok(GenerateUrls());
}
```

Comment: While that works around the described problem, it does not really answer my question. There are good reasons for the `Async` suffix convention - dropping it is not really an option in my case. I am looking for a type-safe way to use `Url.Action` even _when_ the methods have the `Async` suffix.

Comment: @janw did you find a solution for this?