# Partial evaluation of expressions

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I want to capture a method call as an expression, but evaluate its arguments in a type-safe and IDE-friendly way beforehand.

Take the following example class:

```cs
class Test
{
    public string SomeMethod(int a, string b) { ... }
}
```

I now want to pass a call to `SomeMethod` to a function receiving an `Expression`:

```cs
HandleMethodCall<Test>(test => test.SomeMethod("string".Length, 5.ToString()));
```

Right now `HandleMethodCall` has the signature

```cs
static void HandleMethodCall<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
```

Unfortunately, in this case the expression passed to `HandleMethodCall` does not only contain `test.SomeMethod()`, but expression trees for the arguments as well.

A workaround would be to split the method call and its arguments into different arguments for `HandleMethodCall`, but this has the cost of losing compile-time type-safety and IDE support for showing argument names.

Is there any way to make the compiler evaluate parts of an expression before putting them into an `Expression` object?

Or, alternatively, is it possible to manually invoke evaluation of the expression trees for the method parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean by, "manually invoke evaluation of the expression trees for the method parameters" - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-execute-expression-trees) ?

Comment: Hmm, that might work - so you propose creating a `Expression<Func<T>>` from the expression tree of each argument and run it?

Comment: If that is what you meant by your post, then that is the only thing I can think of to do for evaluating your parameters.

Comment: Of course, you will have an issue trying to get the type `T` for the arguments at compile time. Why do you need to evaluate the arguments separately from the call?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, I had to work around using `Func<object>` and `Expression.Convert()`. I will self-answer after completing my experiments, if no one else does :)  I try to build a type-safe variant of `Url.Action()` for ASP.NET Core (follow up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969091/using-nameof-with-url-action-and-async-methods-in-asp-net-core-3-x-mvc)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to specify this at compile time, but one can compile and evaluate the expression parts at runtime using `Expression.Lambda<>(...).Compile()()` (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-execute-expression-trees)).

This results in the following implementation (no error checking for sake of simplicity):

```cs
public static void HandleMethodCall<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    // Extract method call
    var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;

    // Run through expected arguments and evaluate the supplied ones
    var expectedArguments = methodCall.Method.GetParameters();
    for(int i = 0; i < expectedArguments.Length; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write(expectedArguments[i].Name + ": ");

        // Since we do not know the argument type in advance, we have to use Func<object>
        var argumentEvaluationExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(methodCall.Arguments[i], typeof(object)));
        object argumentValue = argumentEvaluationExpression.Compile()();

        Console.WriteLine(argumentValue);
    }
}
```

Calling this function with

```cs
HandleMethodCall<Test>(test => test.SomeMethod("string".Length, "1" + " 2 " + (1 + 2).ToString()));
```

outputs the expected result

```
a: 6
b: 1 2 3
```

However, I am not sure whether this will really work under all conditions. In addition, I expect this to be [quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35805610/8528014) due to the `Compile()` step.

Thanks to @RyanWilson for the helpful comments, which allowed me to figure out this solution!